# How to remove MAUI NavBar when using Embedded WebView?

Tags: webview, android-webview, maui, azure-ad-msal

I am using the Microsoft.Identity.Client in MAUI .NET7 and for some reason when calling the PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive the embedded webview has a NavBar that I can't get rid of.

[image: AcquireTokenInteractive]

I have tried using AppShell and regular NavigationPage.
I have the Title set to "" and on the window invoking the AcquireTokenInteractive I have these set:
             `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"`

I can't seem to hide nor customise this.

[image: Tried all 3 page variations]

Note: this is only an issue on Android

Comment: `I have tried using AppShell and regular NavigationPage.` But what was your code exactly? As a test, In App.xaml.cs, change the line `MainPage = new AppShell();` to be `MainPage = new YourWebViewPage();` Substitute the name of the page that contains the webview. Is the nav bar still there? If so, then it must be part of the web page that AcquireTokenInteractive displays, not something added by Maui.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my `AppShell.xaml` looks and the navigation bar is hidden. But I only have that one page in the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="My.Namespace.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Namespace"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```